# Error while building on build server

Tags: android

I have this build.gradle file. The code build fine in Android Studio but when I try to build it on TeamCity, I get this exception:

> Process exited with code 1 [20:20:27][Step 1/1] Gradle failure report
>   [20:20:27][Gradle failure report] FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception. [20:20:27][Gradle failure report]  [20:20:27][Gradle
>   failure report] * What went wrong: [20:20:27][Gradle failure report]
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   [20:20:27][Gradle failure report] >
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit
>   value 1 [20:20:27][Gradle failure report]

Here is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    //buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aaaaaaaa.aaaa.aaaa"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
//        jackOptions {
//            enabled true
//        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

//    compileOptions {
//        targetCompatibility 1.8
//        sourceCompatibility 1.8
//    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'
    compile 'org.adw.library:discrete-seekbar:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.jjobes:SlideDateTimePicker:v1.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.alirezaaa:FilePickerLibrary:3.5.1'
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.25.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.hkm.ui:ultimaterecyclerview:0.5.8'
    compile 'com.mlsdev.rximagepicker:library:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
}
```

Is there anything else I need to add in gradle file to build it on TeamCity?

Comment: Did you add this to your manifest `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

Comment: Yes I have added this in android manifest file but still same error. No luck!!!